# How to subtract System.currentTimeMillis() from Hours+Minutes taken from timepicker?

Tags: java, android

I want to subtract the `System.currentTimeMillis()` from Hours + Minutes taken from timepicker. However, the `System.currentTimeMillis()` is much larger as compared to Hours + Minutes converted to `MilliSeconds`.

This is my code:

```
// setting my time in milliseconds. hour1 and minute1 taken from timepicker.
app.setTimeMillisDosageTime(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hour1) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minute1));
```

I have a `TimerTask` where I am subtracting the `System.currentTimeMillis`.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    timeInMillis = app.getTimeMillisDosageTime();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
           long ellapsedMillis = timeinMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        timer = new Timer(false);
        timer.schedule(task,0,1000);
    }
}
```

But my `elapsedMillis` is always negative. Any solution?

Comment: I think you should subtract `timeinMillis` from `currentTimeMillis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis  
// given number is converted to milliseconds. if you give 1 as input 60*60*1000 is output.
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1) = 60* 60 * 1000
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1) = 60  * 1000 

System.currentTimeMillis() //milli seconds elapsed from January 1, 1970 UTC(coordinated universal time)
```

But what you require is these hour and minutes set to current date, then counting how many seconds elapsed from 1970.

```
Calendar chosenTime = Calendar.getInstance();
chosenTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
chosenTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

chosenTime.getTime().get(Time)  // This gives you exact seconds that can be substracted from System.currentTimeMillis.
```